# Is it possible to make an operating system around a single program?

Tags: boot, application-launch

I was wondering if it is possible to make a computer run a program, but only that program. you boot it up and it goes immediately into that application, and it is used expressly for that application. Operating system or no, is this possible?

Comment: Like this? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiosk_software

Comment: Yes.  That is what embedded systems typically do, e.g. a set-top box running Kodi or wireless routers running OpenWrt.

Comment: Yes, just like that.But is there any way I can do it for an application of my choice though?